# Solving $a + b + c + d = 100$, where $a \gt b + c$, $b = c$, and $c \gt d$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'd like some help solving a simple system of linear equations. I'm designing a function that gives a score to certain keywords based on ranking and I want to figure out the math. Here is an example:

> Solve the equation, $a + b + c + d = 100$
> $a \gt b + c$
> $b = c$
> $c \gt d$

In this case, I want to find values for $a, b, c,$ and $d$. "$a$" is the highest rank, $b$ and $c$ are rank 2 and $d$ is rank 3. All of the variables added together should equal 100. all variables are positive real numbers.

How do I solve this system of linear equations and find a fixed value for each variable?

Thank you and please let me know if I can make this question more clear. It's been a while since I've done linear algebra and any help solving (and showing how to get the answer) is very helpful.

Comment: You forgot to say what $a,b,c,d$ are - integers? Or real numbers?

Comment: There's plenty of solutions. What about $60,20,20,0$ ?

Comment: If $b=c$, is it really worth having two variables ?

Comment: thanks for these comments. I updated it

Comment: @YvesDaoust how did you go about getting those values?

Comment: As they say, by inspection. $d=0$ is harmless, then split $100$ in $a+2b$ unevenly.

Comment: i don't see it from inspection. would it be possible to show me how y ou solve it and come up with a single value for each variable? thanks!

Comment: What don't you understand in my comment ?

Answer (score 0):

you can write $$a+2b+d=100$$ since $$b=c$$ further we get
$$a>2b-d>b+d$$
Can you go on?
From the last on we get
$$100-2b>d$$ amd $$c>d$$ (given)
It is onl $$2b$$
I got
$$100>c+2d+3b$$
From here you will get an example

Comment: Thanks; i have a questions. Where did you get a = b? in my equation, a is greater than the sum and b and c.

Comment: Sorry this was a typo

Comment: It must be $$b=c$$ it was a typo,sorry.

Comment: Got it. How would i go about finding a single positive real number value for each variable? and would you show a bit more how you arrived at that last equation? how do you deal with mixed "=" signs and a ">" sign?

Comment: also how did you get 10b?

Comment: I see it was changed. How would i go about finding a single value for each variable? thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

What I should do is to minimize
$$\Phi(a,b,c,d)=(a+b+c+d-100)^2$$ subject to the different constraints.

For your example, without positivity constraint, the result would be $\left\{64,22,22,-8\right\}$ and for this solution $a+b+c+d=100$.

If they must be positive, then $\left\{45,\frac{41}{2},\frac{41}{2},14\right\}$ and $a+b+c+d=100$ again

Comment: Thanks. It's been a long time since i did ilnera algebra. I don't follow you steps. do you mind showing me how you arrived at them? thanks

Comment: This is quadratic optimization under linear equality/inequality constraints.

Comment: Got it. I haven't encountered that (at least its been so long I don't remember it). Do you mind showing me how you got that and i'll read up on the technique? thanks!